# Issue with my drag and drop plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, drag-and-drop

I'm currently developing a `Drag n' Drop` plugin. I have just finished a feature so people could `drop` the `draggable` item on a target. Now it works perfect on the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/XvZLn/18/

But once I implement that code into my plugin the following wont work:

```
var target = {
    on: function() {
        return $('.drag:first').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('i');
        });
    },
    off: function() {
        $('.drag:first').removeClass('i');
    }
};
```

Which in my plugin it looks like this:

```
var targ = {
    on: o.target.onTarget,
    off: o.target.offTarget
};
```

Both of the codes have there purposes. The the `on` part is the function that is suppose to be launched when you enter all the way in the target. The `off` part is the function that gets launched when leaving the target.

`onTarget` and `offTarget` are all options in the `defaults`.
The reason we this var is because we needed a way to use `function(){}`.

The only way I thought I could do this is in an var.
Now Im trying to launch `targ.on()` inside the if that checks if the element is all the way inside the target. This is not working. I know the `targ.on()` is not working because I added an alert in the if and and I got the alert once the element got in the target.

This the the full code I use in my plugin:

```
var locker = o.target.lock;
var lock = false;
var targ = {
    on: o.target.onTarget,
    off: o.target.offTarget
};
$(oj).bind('drag', function (event) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var $con = $(o.target.init);
    if (lock === false) {
        $(this).css({
            top: event.offsetY,
            left: event.offsetX
        });
    }
}).bind('mouseup', function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    var $con = $(o.target.init);
    var sen = 100;
    var otop = $t.offset().top;
    var oleft = $t.offset().left;
    var conw = $con.width();
    var conh = $con.height();
    var cono = $con.offset().top;
    var conl = $con.offset().left;
    var oo = $t.height();
    sen = sen * 2;
    var other = oleft <= conw - (sen / 1.25) && oleft > conl && oleft < conw + conl - (sen / 4);
    if (locker === false) {
        if (otop < conw - (sen / 4) && otop > cono && otop < ((conh + cono) - oo) && other) {
            targ.on();
            lock = false;
        } else {
            targ.off();
            lock = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (otop < conw - (sen / 4) && otop > cono && otop < ((conh + cono) - oo) && other) {
            targ.on();
            $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
            lock = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Full Plugin Code:

```
$.setCookie = function(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays === null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
};
$.getCookie = function(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
};
$.fn.jDrag = function(options) {
    var getVersion = {
        version: '1.0.0',
        version2: '1.0.0',
        version3: '1.0.1'
    };
    var defaults = {
        revert: false,
        revertDuration: 500,
        ghostDrop: false,
        ghostRevert: false,
        ghostOpacity: '0.50',
        instantGhost: false,
        activeClass: false,
        handle: false,
        grid: false,
        cookies: false,
        cookieExdate: 365,
        radialDrag: false,
        radius: 100,
        circularOutline: false,
        strictMovement: false,
        distance: 0,
        not: false,
        containment: false,
        target: {
            init: false,
            lock: false,
            onTarget: function() {},
            offTarget: function() {}
        },
        onPickUp: function() {},
        onDrop: function() {}
    };
    var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
    $('body').append('<span class="version_usage_neededToReCievever_srion-now" style="display:none;">' + getVersion.version2 + '</span>');
    return this.each(function() {

        //Some Variables
        var oj = this,
            position = $(oj).position(),
            revertLeft = position.left,
            revertTop = position.top,
            yea = 'body',
            onceInawhile = '<b class="getDistanceAsofPosition" style="display:none;">' + o.distance + '</b>';
        if (o.not === oj) {
            o.not = false;
        }
        o.distance = squared(o.distance);
        //alert(o.distance);
        var m;
        var t;
        $(oj).bind('mousedown', function() {
            m = event.pageX;
            t = event.pageY;
            //$('#hi').text(m+' '+t);
        });
        var firstofdrag = '<b class="getnotNoCondition" style="display:none;">"' + o.not + '"</b>';
        if (o.ghostDrop === true) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999);
            if (o.ghostRevert === false) {
                o.revert = false;
            }
            if (o.ghostRevert === true) {
                o.revert = true;
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(oj).clone().attr('id', '').addClass('ghosts').addClass('ghost_starter' + random).css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: revertTop,
                    left: revertLeft,
                    opacity: o.ghostOpacity
                }).appendTo('body');

                $('.ghost_starter' + random).mousedown(function() {
                    if (o.activeClass !== false) {
                        $(this).addClass(o.activeClass);
                    }
                }).bind('mousedown', o.onPickUp).bind('drag', function(event) {
                    if (o.grid !== false) {
                        if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'horizontal' || o.strictMovement === 'x') {
                                $(this).css('left', Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[0]) * defaults.grid[0]);
                            }
                            else if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'vertical' || o.strictMovement === 'y') {
                                $(this).css('top', Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[1]) * defaults.grid[1]);
                            } else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: Math.round(event.offsetY / defaults.grid[1]) * defaults.grid[1],
                                    left: Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[0]) * defaults.grid[0]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (o.containment !== false) {
                        var $div = (o.containment === 'parent') ? $(oj).parent() : ((o.containment === 'parent parent') ? $(oj).parent().parent() : ((o.containment === 'document') ? $(document) : $(o.containment)));
                        var j, b, r;
                        $('.ghost_starter' + random).bind("dragstart", function(event) {
                            j = $div.offset();
                            b = j.top + $div.outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight();
                            r = j.left + $div.outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth();
                        }).bind('drag', function(event) {
                            $(this).css({
                                top: Math.min(b, Math.max(j.top, event.offsetY)),
                                left: Math.min(r, Math.max(j.left, event.offsetX))
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else {

                        if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'horizontal' || o.strictMovement === 'x') {
                                $(this).css('left', event.offsetX);
                            }
                            else if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'vertical' || o.strictMovement === 'y') {
                                $(this).css('top', event.offsetY);
                            } else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: event.offsetY,
                                    left: event.offsetX
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).bind('mouseup', o.onDrop);
                $(window).mouseup(function() {
                    if (o.activeClass !== false) {
                        $('.ghost_starter' + random).removeClass(o.activeClass);
                    }
                    var gpos = $('.ghost_starter' + random).position(),
                        lft = gpos.left,
                        tp = gpos.top;
                    $(oj).animate({
                        top: tp,
                        left: lft
                    }, 300);
                    if (o.cookies !== false) {
                        var cookies = $('.ghost_starter' + random).position();
                        if (o.cookieExdate === 'browserClose') {
                            $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Top-Ghost' + $('.ghost_starter' + random).index(), cookies.top);
                            $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Left-Ghost' + $('.ghost_starter' + random).index(), cookies.left);
                        } else {
                            $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Top-Ghost' + $('.ghost_starter' + random).index(), cookies.top, o.cookieExdate);
                            $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Left-Ghost' + $('.ghost_starter' + random).index(), cookies.left, o.cookieExdate);
                        }
                    }
                });

            });

        }
        if (o.distance !== false) {
            $(yea).append(onceInawhile);
        }
        $('body').append('<span class="version_usage_neededToReCievever_srion-future" style="display:none;">' + getVersion.version3 + '</span>');
        if (o.radialDrag === true) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                if (o.circularOutline === true) {
                    $('head').append('<span class="hi"><div class="circularStyle"></div></span>');
                    $('.circularStyle').html('<style type="text/css">.pointlikeamaster{' + 'position: absolute;height: 4px;width: 4px;' + 'margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;background: #A00;' + '}</style>');
                }
            });
            $(oj).bind('dragstart', function(event) {
                var data = $(this).data('dragcircle');
                if (data) {
                    data.$circle.show();
                }
                else {
                    data = {
                        radius: o.radius,
                        $circle: $([]),
                        halfHeight: $(this).outerHeight() / 2,
                        halfWidth: $(this).outerWidth() / 2
                    };
                    data.centerX = event.offsetX + data.radius + data.halfWidth;
                    data.centerY = event.offsetY + data.halfHeight;
                    // create divs to highlight the path...
                    $.each(new Array(72), function(i, a) {
                        angle = Math.PI * ((i - 36) / 36);
                        data.$circle = data.$circle.add(
                        $('<div class="pointlikeamaster" />').css({
                            top: data.centerY + Math.cos(angle) * data.radius,
                            left: data.centerX + Math.sin(angle) * data.radius
                        }));
                    });
                    $(this).after(data.$circle).data('dragcircle', data);
                }
            }).bind('drag', function(event) {
                var data = $(this).data('dragcircle'),
                    angle = Math.atan2(event.pageX - data.centerX, event.pageY - data.centerY);
                $(this).css({
                    top: data.centerY + Math.cos(angle) * data.radius - data.halfHeight,
                    left: data.centerX + Math.sin(angle) * data.radius - data.halfWidth
                });
            }).bind('dragend', function() {
                $(this).data('dragcircle').$circle.hide();
            });

        } else {
            $(oj).mousedown(function() {
                if (o.activeClass !== false) {
                    $(this).addClass(o.activeClass);
                }
            }).bind('mousedown', o.onPickUp);

            if (o.handle !== false) {
                $(o.handle).mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        cursor: 'crosshair'
                    });
                });
                $(oj).bind('dragstart', function(event) {
                    if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return $(event.target).is(o.handle);
                    }
                }).bind('drag', function(event) {
                    if (o.grid !== false) {
                        if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'horizontal' || o.strictMovement === 'x') {
                                $(this).css('left', Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[0]) * defaults.grid[0]);
                            }
                            else if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'vertical' || o.strictMovement === 'y') {
                                $(this).css('top', Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[1]) * defaults.grid[1]);
                            } else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: Math.round(event.offsetY / defaults.grid[1]) * defaults.grid[1],
                                    left: Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[0]) * defaults.grid[0]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else if (o.containment !== false) {
                        var $div = (o.containment === 'parent') ? $(oj).parent() : ((o.containment === 'parent parent') ? $(oj).parent().parent() : ((o.containment === 'document') ? $(document) : $(o.containment)));
                        var j, b, r;
                        $(oj).bind("dragstart", function(event) {
                            j = $div.offset();
                            b = j.top + $div.outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight();
                            r = j.left + $div.outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth();
                        }).bind('drag', function(event) {
                            $(this).css({
                                top: Math.min(b, Math.max(j.top, event.offsetY)),
                                left: Math.min(r, Math.max(j.left, event.offsetX))
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'horizontal' || o.strictMovement === 'x') {
                                $(this).css('left', event.offsetX);
                            }
                            else if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'vertical' || o.strictMovement === 'y') {
                                $(this).css('top', event.offsetY);
                            } else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: event.offsetY,
                                    left: event.offsetX
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $(oj).bind('drag', function(event) {

                    if (o.grid !== false) {
                        if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'horizontal') {
                                $(this).css('left', Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[0]) * defaults.grid[0]);
                            }
                            else if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'vertical') {
                                $(this).css('top', Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[1]) * defaults.grid[1]);
                            } else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: Math.round(event.offsetY / defaults.grid[1]) * defaults.grid[1],
                                    left: Math.round(event.offsetX / defaults.grid[0]) * defaults.grid[0]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (o.containment !== false) {
              var $div = (o.containment === 'parent') ? $(oj).parent() : ((o.containment === 'parent parent') ? $(oj).parent().parent() : ((o.containment === 'document') ? $(document) : $(o.containment)));
                        var j, b, r;
                        $(oj).bind("dragstart", function(event) {
                            j = $div.offset();
                            b = j.top + $div.outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight();
                            r = j.left + $div.outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth();
                        }).bind('drag', function(event) {
                            $(this).css({
                                top: Math.min(b, Math.max(j.top, event.offsetY)),
                                left: Math.min(r, Math.max(j.left, event.offsetX))
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else if (o.target.init !== false) {
/*
Use this to adjust the target settings
 $('b').html(otop+' < '+(conw - (sen/4))+' && '+otop+' > '+cono+' && '+otop+' <= '+((conh + cono)-oo)+' && '+oleft+' < '+(conw-(sen/1.25))+' && '+oleft+' > '+conl+' && '+oleft+' < '+(conw + conl-(sen/4)));
        var other = oleft <= conw - (sen/1.25) && oleft > conl && oleft < conw + conl - (sen / 4);
*/
                        var locker = o.target.lock;
                        var lock = false;
                        var targ = {
                            on: o.target.onTarget,
                            off: o.target.offTarget
                        };
                        $(oj).bind('drag', function(event) {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            var $con = $(o.target.init);
                            if (lock === false) {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: event.offsetY,
                                    left: event.offsetX
                                });
                            }
                        }).bind('mouseup', function() {
                            var $t = $(this);
                            var $con = $(o.target.init);
                            var sen = 100;
                            var otop = $t.offset().top;
                            var oleft = $t.offset().left;
                            var conw = $con.width();
                            var conh = $con.height();
                            var cono = $con.offset().top;
                            var conl = $con.offset().left;
                            var oo = $t.height();
                            sen = sen * 2;
                            var other = oleft <= conw - (sen / 1.25) && oleft > conl && oleft < conw + conl - (sen / 4);
                            if (locker === false) {
                                if (otop < conw - (sen / 4) && otop > cono && otop < ((conh + cono) - oo) && other) {
                                    targ.on();
                                    lock = false;
                                } else {
                                    targ.off();
                                    lock = false;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (otop < conw - (sen / 4) && otop > cono && otop < ((conh + cono) - oo) && other) {
                                    targ.on();
                                    $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
                                    lock = true;
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    } else {
                        if (o.not !== false && $(event.target).is(o.not)) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'horizontal') {
                                $(this).css('left', event.offsetX);
                            }
                            else if (o.strictMovement !== false || o.strictMovement === 'vertical') {
                                $(this).css('top', event.offsetY);
                            } else {
                                $(this).css({
                                    top: event.offsetY,
                                    left: event.offsetX
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            $(oj).bind('mouseup', o.onDrop);
            $(window).mouseup(function() {
                if (o.activeClass !== false) {
                    $(oj).removeClass(o.activeClass);
                }
                if (o.revert === true) {
                    $(oj).animate({
                        top: revertTop,
                        left: revertLeft
                    }, o.revertDuration);
                }
                if (o.cookies !== false) {
                    var cookies = $(oj).position();
                    if (o.cookieExdate === 'browserClose') {
                        $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Top' + $(oj).index(), cookies.top);
                        $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Left' + $(oj).index(), cookies.left);
                    } else {
                        $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Top' + $(oj).index(), cookies.top, o.cookieExdate);
                        $.setCookie('jDrag-Position-Left' + $(oj).index(), cookies.left, o.cookieExdate);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        if (o.not !== false) {
            $(yea).append(firstofdrag);
        }
        $('body').append('<span class="version_usage_neededToReCievever_srion-past" style="display:none;">' + getVersion.version + '</span>');
        if (o.instantGhost === true) {
            window.setInterval(function() {
                var gpos = $('.ghost_starter' + random).position(),
                    lft = gpos.left,
                    tp = gpos.top;
                $(oj).stop(true, false).animate({
                    top: tp,
                    left: lft
                }, 200);
            }, 200);
        }
        //End normal Dragging
        //End Tags
        if (o.cookies === false) {
            $(function() {
                var oj = this;
                if (o.ghostDrop === true) {
                    var savedLeftPosition = $.getCookie('jDrag-Position-Left-Ghost' + $(oj).index()),
                        savedTopPosition = $.getCookie('jDrag-Position-Top-Ghost' + $(oj).index());
                    $(oj).css({
                        left: savedLeftPosition + 'px',
                        top: savedTopPosition + 'px'
                    });
                    $('.ghost_starter' + random).css({
                        left: savedLeftPosition + 'px',
                        top: savedTopPosition + 'px'
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            var savedLeftPosition1 = $.getCookie('jDrag-Position-Left' + $(oj).index()),
                savedTopPosition1 = $.getCookie('jDrag-Position-Top' + $(oj).index());
            $(oj).css({
                left: savedLeftPosition1 + 'px',
                top: savedTopPosition1 + 'px'
            });
        }

    });
};
```

I had to leave out the top part of the plugin because it told me there is a 30000 character limit.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDUZL/84/

Im not sure what the problem is, and im not sure if this is too much information or not. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you provide the entire plugin code and a link to an example using the plugin?

Comment: The entire plugin code is over 600 lines

Comment: @Shawn31313 It will automatically put in scroll bars so it won't make this page too long.

Comment: This isn't enough info. We need to see o.target and/or onTarget and offTarget definitions.

Comment: There you go. @Jed go to the bottom of the javascript in my jsfiddle and look at the default in `$('#id').jDrag({defaults});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in your first jsFiddle because you're relying on the offset directly from the drag event object:

```
$('.drag').bind('drag', function(event) {
    var $t = $(this);
    var $con = $('#container');
    if (lock === false) {
        $(this).css({
            top: event.offsetY, // coordinates directly from event object
            left: event.offsetX
        });
    }
})...
```

In the full plugin code, you get an offset in your dragstart event callback and then try to reference it from your drag event callback. The problem is that this dragstart event is not being triggered (or not at the proper time or on the proper element, anyway). When the drag callback looks for the values, they're undefined and your script is halted on the error. See here for reference:

```
var $div = (o.containment === 'parent') ? $(oj).parent() : ((o.containment === 'parent parent') ? $(oj).parent().parent() : ((o.containment === 'document') ? $(document) : $(o.containment)));

var j, b, r;

$('.ghost_starter' + random).bind("dragstart", function(event) { // this event isn't being triggered (or at least not at the right time or on the right element)...
  j = $div.offset();
  b = j.top + $div.outerHeight() - $(this).outerHeight();
  r = j.left + $div.outerWidth() - $(this).outerWidth();
}).bind('drag', function(event) {               
  $(this).css({
    top: Math.min(b, Math.max(j.top, event.offsetY)), // ...so b, j, and r aren't defined here
    left: Math.min(r, Math.max(j.left, event.offsetX))
  });
});
```

Fix that dragstart trigger or get your offset otherwise and you'll be set.

Comment: The Second snippet of code is just for another feature. I dont get it.

Comment: This other feature is causing an error in your code that is preventing everything after it from working. You need to fix it before you can go forward.

Comment: I don't have time to go that deep into your code right now but I recommend you first check to make sure that `'.ghost_starter' + random` is the element that `dragstart` is being triggered on. If so, check the order of events to make sure that `dragstart` is being triggered synchronously before `drag`. One of those two has to be the problem. (Are you sure this is your plugin? :-)